# Reading RSS feed with SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, twig

I am having problem with displaying content block from this RSS feed -  [PHP.NET](http://php.net/feed.atom)

How can I disply all HTML element like a, p li using SimpleXML and Twig?

```
<content type="xhtml">
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

 <p>The PHP development team announces the immediate availability of PHP
 5.4.37. Six security-related bugs were fixed in this release, including CVE-2015-0231, CVE-2014-9427
 and CVE-2015-0232.

 All PHP 5.4 users are encouraged to upgrade to this version.
 </p>

 <p>For source downloads of PHP 5.4.37 please visit our <a href="http://www.php.net/downloads.php">downloads page</a>,
 Windows binaries can be found on <a href="http://windows.php.net/download/">windows.php.net/download/</a>.
 The list of changes is recorded in the <a href="http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.4.37">ChangeLog</a>.
 </p>
</div>
```

Thank U for help.

Comment: What a difference with the previous question?

Comment: The difference is that i want to get only elements which belongs to specific content element ( last time i got array of all a elements inside content from document)

Comment: How distinguish that block from other content blocks? What a rule?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/nn98vjf5n/ - I am trying to do it like on this img, but i can't display matching a,p for each block using ur method.

Comment: do you want make loop with content blocks and find that elements for each block? You can use relative xpath - if $el - "content" block `$el->xpath(.//` (Xpath beginning with point) will work with inner content of $el